# Java Language Detection

Tags: java, language-translation

actually, i'm using java Language Detection to detect a text language, and i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.util.LangProfile.name from class com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.DetectorFactory
```

here is my code :

```
    public static String landDetect(String text) throws LangDetectException {
         String profileDirectory ="D:\\Spam Detection PFE 2016\\profiles";
        try {
            DetectorFactory.loadProfile(profileDirectory);
        } catch (LangDetectException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(attribute_functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
        detector.append(text);
    return(detector.detect());

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try [reporting this](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/issues) to the library instead seeking support from stackoverflow, since your code seems to be the same as [official sample](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/blob/wiki/ProjectHome.md).

Comment: Is the `name` field private in LangProfile? It appears to be trying to access that field but it cannot.

Comment: I've found the solution, i had added two jar files versions ; instead of one.
Thank youuu